# Upload file on every save with Rsync

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, synchronization, rsync

Im using Eclipse PDT(Ubuntu 10.10) for web development and successfully uploading changed files with Rsync manually.

```
~$ rsync -e ssh -av /home/goksel/Sites/test goksel@goksel.com:test
sending incremental file list
test/
test/index.php
```

Is there a way to make this command work on every save?

I know that I can do this by using Aptana's Sync tool but somehow it works very slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 options available.  If you right-click on the project you can add an external builder, which can be an ant file or a program.  That will run on every file change.

The second option is to use something like Remote System Explorer from Target Management: http://www.eclipse.org/tm/ A lot of users use this when working on projects (like PHP) that they want synced up to a remote system.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Im gonna check these options soon.

Comment: External builder doesn't seem to work - except when going to run configurations, running. Never "just works" on save.

Comment: Using ant as external builder solution to sync file with remote SSH server is explained in http://blog.robert.mcfrazier.com/rsync-on-save-in-eclipse-on-osx/

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using RSE is that it conflicts with other Team connections such as subversion. RSE was also very slow and worked in batches (just like sending a SVN changeset to the SVN server).

Comment: Yep couldn't agree with you more. When the project is remote it doesn't seem like Eclipse fully understands what's going on. References are missing, code search is very slow and the project doesn't act like a PyDev project. Running rsync might be a much better solution, if I can figure out how to get it to sync on save. Another option is to use SVN or GIT and just add a post-commit hook.